# Does the word "embarrassedly" exist?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, difference, word-formation

My sister is an English learner. In her English exam I noticed this sentence:

> She just smiled ...... when her friends reminded of the day she slept in class. (EMBARRASS)

The answer given is **embarrassedly**

However, I couldn't find that word in online dictionaries such as Oxford, Cambridge or Longman, but I did see some examples of *embarrassedly* used in sentences.
That's the same case with 'interestedly'

I'm so confused. Can I use *embarrassingly* instead?

Comment: An example of it, https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/embarrassedly

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *embarrassingly*, because that would mean that the smile caused other people to feel embarrassed.

*Embarrassedly* is a valid word, but it's not very easy to say, so we often use phrases like *in an embarrassed way* instead.

Comment: So in some cases, embarrassedly and interestedly can be used eventhough they are not included in dictionary?

Comment: _Embarrassedly_ is included [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embarrassed#other-words). _Interestedly_ is in the Macmillan dictionary.

Comment: It's common to form an adverb by adding -ly to an adjective (or a past participle functioning as an adjective), even if the adverb isn't listed in the dictionary. English lets you construct new words using rules like this.

Comment: Thank you very much!